# Possessive: using it when there's no possession

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

I was asked to clarify why we say *today's lesson* or *tomorrow's world* if by it's very nature possessive only applies to those who possess and therefore it should be theoretically *today lesson*.

Comment: The point is that the so-called "possessive" does not necessarily have anything to do with possessing. It's better to use the term "genitive" for nouns that carry the -_'_ marking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only people possess. Things possess: the land's resources, the moon's gravity. In this case, today "possesses" many things, including a lesson that didn't occur yesterday and won't occur tomorrow. Even abstract nouns can possess: e.g., "Freedom's ring."

In a logical arrangement, you can think of the possessed object as a subset of the possessor. John might be just John, or he could be the set of John and all his things, and John's hat is an element of that set, the hat of John, the hat sub-object that belongs to the set of John and his things. Hence, the lesson of today, today's lesson, to world of tomorrow, tomorrow's world.

> if by it's very nature possessive only applies to those who possess

If that were the case, we'd have *his* and *hers* but not *its*.

Comment: Genitives like this are called "Descriptive Genitives", a somewhat unproductive category of genitive in that some are fine, e.g. "A summer's day", but not *"An Autumn's day".

Comment: So BillJ it would sound natural to say "a summer's day" but not "an autumn's day", do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @elisabetta smith Yes, that's right. Consider also, "a ship's doctor" and "fisherman's cottages" which are both fine, but "a school's doctor" and "country's cottages" which are unacceptable to most people. Strange isn't it?

Comment: "The country's cottages suffered from the heavy snows."

Comment: "A school's doctor ought to concern himself with hazards on the athletic fields."

Comment: I meant "country" in the sense of out of town, not cottages belonging to the nation! "Country's cottages" is ungrammatical; instead we have the plain-case "Those country cottages are charming". And "A school's doctor" is definitely marginal for some, as I said. Again we'd probably use the plain-case "A school doctor".

Comment: In that case we have a semantic ambiguity. I never meant that the nation owned the cottages, just that they stood in the countryside.

Comment: We say "Those country cottage are charming". No one would say *"Those country's cottages are charming", except you it seems.

Comment: In fact I would not say that, and didn't. I'm not sure why you say I would.

Comment: Are you trying to be difficult? You implied that "The country's cottages suffered from the heavy snows" is acceptable. "Country" in your example has the same meaning as "country" in my example, i.e. roughly "countryside". "The country's cottages suffered from the heavy snows." is just as ungrammatical as "Those country's cottages are quite charming". they are both nonsense.

Comment: "The country's cottages" = grammatical construction.
* "Those country's cottages" = ungrammatical construction.
I am not trying to be difficult. I'm sorry you think so. I disagree with your analysis of my previous constructions.